# Xbee Pro 802.15.4 not finding each other when they do not share the same power source?

Tags: xbee

I wasted countless hours and I am completely clueless on a problem with two xbee S1 modules.
I have two 802.15.4 modules which can reach 1.6km.

I have one connected on PC through USB (5V( and a 3.3V linear regulator, scope shows 3.289V with some ripples of 0.2v.

I have another one connected on a battery powered source, again with linear regulator, scope shows 3.299V, very stable voltage.

They are set up for the same PANID and channel, I use the ATND command to discover each other.

There is no chance they find each other, resets, etc will not help.
I have a scope connected, the voltage stays stable at 3.3V.
I have a USB to serial converter connected to both chips (3.3V ttl level of course) and BOTH can be reached through serial.
I can send AT commands to both, so both are powered on and 'should' work.

If I now connect the battery powered one to the same power source which is connected to my PC then suddenly they see each other and everything works as it should.
It is not depending on range, I already made sure of that.

I am left clueless, it makes absolutely no sense.

Anyone with an idea would be very welcome.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The problem is solved, it was a configuration problem.
After factory reset it suddenly worked also when on different sources.

The behaviour is strange but it was not a hardware problem (so not even sure if the offtopic flag and all the friendly downvotes were correct)

Answer (score 1):

(Note: your question is probably better suited for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ I'm an EE so I'll go ahead and try to answer though.)

First, make 100% sure the battery is actually good, and the voltage isn't getting loaded down when it tries to transmit. You can watch the voltage on an oscilloscope to check. (I know you looked at it on a scope, but make sure you do it during operation, not during idle.) If it drops then the battery can't supply enough current. If there's heavy RF noise then you need bigger ceramic power supply bypass capacitors. Those are my top guesses.

If the battery is good, then it's also possible that the antenna connection is bad on one. When they share a power supply, RF might be coupled through the power or ground wire, so they can still talk to each other through the wires instead of through the air. If you try powering them BOTH from the battery, and they start working, this might be what's happening.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.
I made sure the voltage is stable.
I just added a cap to the PC powered one and now the ripple from this one is also gone.

I am sure the voltage is good.


I also thought it might somehow use the power line to communicate with each other, that would be difficult for me to find out :/
The antenna is soldered on it (the xbee comes with a small 2cm antenna). connections look proper for both.

Comment: Hmm; are you able to try powering them both from the battery?

Comment: It was a configuration issue, I did a factory reset on them and reconfigured them. Suddenly it works.
Very strange that they worked when I put them both on the PC regulator but now it seems to be solved.